# how do i resolver numberformatexception error

Tags: android, parsing, error-handling, number-formatting

I am trying to parse a double from an edittext but i keep getting a number format exception error.

i initially tried this...

```
premiumvalue = Double.parseDouble(premium.getText().toString());         
amountweightvalue = Double.parseDouble(amountweight.getText().toString());
```

Then attempted this...to no avail.

```
try{
    premiumvalue = Double.parseDouble(premium.getText().toString());
} catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
    premiumvalue = 0;
}
try{
    amountweightvalue = Double.parseDouble(amountweight.getText().toString());
} catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
    premiumvalue = 0;
}
```

I'm a noob and any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of premium.getText().toString()?

Comment: why are you changing it to toString?

Comment: This might occur when your editText value is empty string " ". Are you checking for this condition?

Comment: try trimming the string before parsing to double.

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava: the value(s) are numeric.  i have the edittext set to only accept numeric values

Comment: @AndroSelva i'm check for it with this...
 if(premium.getText().toString().equals(".")||premium.getText().toString().equals("-.")||premium.getText().toString().equals("")){
    premium.setText("0");
but it is giving me problems as well

Comment: Try it in this manner, if(premium.getText().toString() ==" ")

Comment: check my answer and comment if you still getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have test your code test your code myself and find the following possibility to find `NumberFormatException`:

1. if `EditText` value is blank, `So apply condition for EditText blank value.`
2. if `EditText` value is only dot(.), `So apply condition for EditText dot value.`

in your comment you are saying that you are using this

```
String text = premium.getText().toString();

if(text.equals(".")||text.equals("-.")||text.equals(""))
 { 
    premium.setText("0");
 }
```

so my point is that

1. **are you using same thing for both `premium` and `amountweight` EditText and then parse string to double??**
2. and why you need to check condition for '_' because if you set `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` attribute for EditText then EditText only accept 0-9 and . value.
3. you don't need to trim EditText value bacuse Edittext do not accept blank space if you are using `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` attribute.
4. don't need to check `null` condition because `EditText` never return `null` value.

I have test your code lot of way and do not find `NumberFormatException` if i follow above points.

Comment: code still not working:


   String numberStr = premium.getText().toString();
   double number = Double.parseDouble(numberStr);
if(numberStr.equals(".")||numberStr.equals("-.")||numberStr.equals("")){
    premium.setText("0");
   }else if(number >= 1 && number < 10){
       premium.setText(".0"+numberStr);
      }else if(number >= 10){
    premium.setText("."+numberStr);
   }else if(number <= -1 && number > -10){
       premium.setText(".0"+Math.abs(number));
      }else if(number <= -10){
       premium.setText("."+Math.abs(number));
      }else if(number <1 || number >0){ }

Comment: you have lot of mistake in your code 1. you are always using numberStr which first time calculated. 2. parsing string to double before condition check. 3. why you are setting value with '.' whenever user able to enter '.' in EditText and then two dot will be again reason for Numberformatexception.